# Android Playstore build fails in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am creating a eas build for my expo app. The build is successfully built on iOS but fails in Android. It passes the expo doctor but the build fails in prebuild. I doubt there is something i am doing wrong with permissions in app.json file.

[image] Please let me know if you need anything else.

Node: 18.14.2
npm: 9.6.4
expo: ~47.0.13
react: 18.1.0
react-native: 0.70.8
eas-cli: 3.9.0
Expo Workflow: managed

**Error code**

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/.bin/expo prebuild --no-install --platform android
- Creating native project directories (./ios and ./android) and updating .gitignore
✔ Created native project | gitignore skipped
- Adding Metro bundler config
- Updating your package.json scripts, dependencies, and main file
✔ Updated package.json and added index.js entry point for iOS and Android
- Config syncing
[stderr] 
Using node to generate images. This is much slower than using native packages.
[stderr] 
› Optionally you can stop the process and try again after successfully running `npm install -g sharp-cli`.
- Config syncing
✖ Config sync failed
[stderr] 
TypeError: [android.manifest]: withAndroidManifestBaseMod: androidManifest.manifest.hasOwnProperty is not a function
[stderr] 
TypeError: [android.manifest]: withAndroidManifestBaseMod: androidManifest.manifest.hasOwnProperty is not a function
[stderr] 
    at setAndroidPermissions (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/android/Permissions.js:151:33)
[stderr] 
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/android/Permissions.js:51:31
[stderr] 
    at action (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:235:29)
[stderr] 
    at interceptingMod (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:126:27)
[stderr] 
    at action (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:240:14)
[stderr] 
    at async interceptingMod (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:126:21)
[stderr] 
    at async action (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/createBaseMod.js:71:21)
[stderr] 
    at async interceptingMod (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/withMod.js:126:21)
[stderr] 
    at async evalModsAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/mod-compiler.js:256:25)
[stderr] 
    at async Object.compileModsAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/plugins/mod-compiler.js:160:10)
[stderr] 
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
yarn exited with non-zero code: 1
```

**app.json **

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "CF",
    "slug": "CF",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#00001A"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.anonymous.cf",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.",
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "xxx"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "xxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": ["CAMERA", "CAMERA", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
      "package": "com.anonymous.cf",
      "versionCode": 1
    },


    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxx-xxx-xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.4",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.5",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.4",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "expo": "~47.0.13",
    "expo-av": "~13.0.3",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.4.1",
    "expo-camera": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.2.2",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~3.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.3",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "sharp-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "xml2js": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^11.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have also attached an image of file structure for your reference in case any file is missing.
Thank you.

I tried changes in the app.json and updating the @expo/config-plugins and other dependencies.

Comment: I ran into something similar.  @expo/config-plugins does not seem to be compatible with xml2js 0.5.0 yet.  Try downgrading xml2js to 0.4.23